# Cloudera Manager installation issue in RHEL 5.7

Tags: postgresql, cloudera-manager

We are trying to install CDH 4.4 on RHEL 5.7. But the installation was aborted because of Postgres DB installation issues.

**Logs from /var/log/cloudera-manager-installer/4.install-cloudera-manager-server-db.log**

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager Updating Red Hat repositories. Setting up Install Process Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cloudera-manager-server-db.x86_64 0:4.7.3-1.cm473.p0.163.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: postgresql-server >= 8.0 for package: cloudera-manager-server-db
--> Finished Dependency Resolution cloudera-manager-server-db-4.7.3-1.cm473.p0.163.el5.x86_64 from cloudera-manager has depsolving problems
--> Missing Dependency: postgresql-server >= 8.0 is needed by package cloudera-manager-server-db-4.7.3-1.cm473.p0.163.el5.x86_64 (cloudera-manager) Error: Missing Dependency: postgresql-server >= 8.0 is needed by package cloudera-manager-server-db-4.7.3-1.cm473.p0.163.el5.x86_64 (cloudera-manager) You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem You could try running: package-cleanup --problems package-cleanup --dupes rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

Please let me know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the YUM in your local or use any public Repo to install the dependencies.